# Using a function that has another function as parameter:

Tags: matlab

I want to integrate x^2 from 2 to 4 with the trapezoidal integration method. For this, I  defined a function `trap` that takes 4 arguments:

```
function y = trap( fn, a, b, h )
    n = (b-a)/h;
    x = a + [1:n-1]*h;
    y = h/2*(feval(fn, a) + feval(fn, b) + 2*sum(feval(fn,x)));
```

and a function `f`

```
function y= f(x)
    y=x^2
end
```

Now, by executing `trap(f,2,4,0.1)`, I get the following error:

```
Not enough input arguments.

Error in f (line 2)
    y=x^2
```

**What is the origin of that error?**

Comment: Any reason to avoid [`trapz()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html)?  For example, `xstep = 0.1;` then `X = 2:xstep:4;` then `Area = trapz(X,X.^2)` works great. Decrease `xstep` size for `Area` to converge (with required precision).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `trap` using the function handle `@f`, not `f`.

```
trap(@f,2,4,0.1)

function y = trap( fn, a, b, h )
  n = (b-a)/h;
  x = a + [1:n-1]*h;
  y = h/2*(fn(a) + fn(b) + 2*sum(fn(x)));
end

function y= f(x)
  y = x.^2;
end
```

which gives, as expected,

```
ans =
    18.67
```

Also you needed element-wise multiplication in `f(x)` to compute `y = x.^2`.

And `feval` is not necessary. You can directly call `fn(a)` to evaluate the function.